# Package management and building old software

Tags: centos, yum, package-management

At work we have a vendor supplied library that was delivered to us in the form of C++ headers and `.so` files.  Our production environment has been CentOS 6 for a long time, but we may soon upgrade to CentOS 7.  RPM files have been created both for the library and for our C++ program that uses the library.

I should also mention that the vendor library's dependencies are dynamically linked.

Installing onto new instances of CentOS 6 works fine via `yum`, however on CentOS 7 things go quite poorly. `yum` complains about many packages that it can't find, with python2.6 (i.e. `libpython2.6.so`) as an example.  I can find RPMs for all these various missing dependencies, but in many cases can't install them anyway, as yum says there's "nothing to do" in cases where it would mean a downgrade.

I suppose my question is twofold. Is it possible, as in Python's case, to install another version of Python via `yum`, without it becoming the system version, so that the linker can find it for this old vendor library?

Manually creating all the `.so` files seems like a losing battle, as there a *lot* of missing dependencies, such as `libpng12`, when CentOS 7 has `libpng15`.

What would an experienced sysadmin do in this case? Or is this just a case where making this old program run on CentOS 7 is tilting at windmills?

Comment: The first thing I would do is contact the vendor to see if there is an update.

Comment: You should adopt the binaries and libraries to the CentOS7 delivered libraries, which means recompile anything you can on CentOS7 and repackage it as RPM. If you cannot rebuild it, contact the vendor. It is bad to copy old binaries and libraries to a newer distribution and carry on with old libraries.

Comment: Also make contingency plans to discontinue use of this library and replace it (and possibly the hardware to which it is associated) with something else.

Comment: Would it be possible to update you r spec files so that the later versions of dependencies are used rather than giving errors ?